# WebRequest doesn't work with proxy

Tags: c#, proxy

The code below works fine without proxy:

```
System.IO.Stream feedStream = null;
System.Net.WebRequest feedClient = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(@"https://api.pinnaclesports.com/v1/feed?sportid=29&last=1414860831010&oddsformat=1&currencycode=USD");
feedClient.Proxy = new WebProxy("80.232.234.114", 8080);
string authInfo = "???:??"; // login and password here
authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
feedClient.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;
System.Net.WebResponse feedResp = feedClient.GetResponse();//!
feedStream = feedResp.GetResponseStream();
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(feedStream, Encoding.UTF8);
String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

But when using a proxy, it gives the error:

> ```
> "The remote server returned an error: (501) Not Implemented." in line '//!'
> ```

Why? I have tried another proxy, the same problem happens.

Comment: Are you sure your proxy supports Basic authentication? Would you try to use Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password") and set UseDefaultCredentials = false?

Comment: Basic authentication required api.pinnaclesport.com. All working without "feedClient.Proxy = new WebProxy("80.232.234.114", 8080);". But I must to use proxy.